# C# Telerik reporting no datasource at designtime dataschema

Tags: c#, telerik, report

I use vs 2010 and telerik reporting 2013 Q1

use the next code to bind a datatable to report.

```
Reports.Report1 report = new Reports.Report1();

Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource objectDataSource = new Telerik.Reporting.ObjectDataSource();
objectDataSource.DataSource = CreateData().Tables[0];
report.DataSource = objectDataSource;          

Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource reportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
reportSource.ReportDocument = report;
TelRptViewer.ReportSource = reportSource;
```

My report contains a simple table dataitem with 3 columns.
I have already read this topic in help.
[Working With Data at Design Time-Data source available only at runtime](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/connecting-to-data-working-with-data-at-design-time.html)

"This approach is useful when you cannot get the report's data source at design time or want to avoid loading real data into Visual Studio at design time. In this case you would have to mock your data just to enable the Report Designer to show any data schema. This will enable you to adjust the layout of the report and bind report items to the available data fields, while the real data will be loaded only at runtime either in NeedDataSource event or in the actual application. "

In simple reportviewer there was an xsd which prove the data schema for report.
In this viewer how its is possible to make this data schema or similar? Or there is another way to do this?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You never said whether you have added report items (e.g. TextBoxes) in your Report1 class. Those textboxes need to have binding expressions as Value i.e. = Fields.MyDataColumn1.

Only then, would the report actually show data. You could also add a call to TelRptViewer.RefreshReport(); which is required for some viewers (e.g. Windows Forms)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind Telerik Reports to objectdatasource at design time and drag your fields directly to the REport using Visual Designer
To create and run the reports using Visual Studio or the new Desginer while binding it to a objectdatasource : All you have to do is hardcode the connection string into the class of your data method . and inside that method use the connection string. Check my blog: http://flying2mind.blogspot.com/2013/10/creatingrunning-telerik-reports-in.html

http://flying2mind.blogspot.com/2013/07/telerik-report-doesnt-see-fields-of.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can add your datasource code in NeedDataSource event of your report and set the datasource. NeedDataSource event is used when there is no data source for the report.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Report1_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report rpt = (Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report)sender;
    this.Report1DS.Parameters[0].Value = your value to be passed to data source..;
    // Similarly you can add more values of parameters.
    rpt.DataSource = Report1DS;
}
```